# How to capture asynchronous ajax response into a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making the following jquery ajax call to a codeigniter php function:

```
    var html ="";

    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "Ajax/getHtml",
                        data: { u : contents },
                        dataType: 'html',       
                        success: function(data) {
                            html = data;
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

                     console.log('html', html);
```

This is working correctly and html is being returned on success which I can see if I log 'data' to the console. However I don't seem to be able to capture the HTML response in a javascript variable. I have declared one (html) globally. When I look at the console I see:

```
html 
jquery-2.1.1.js:8623 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/b1/Ajax/getHtml".
```

I'm not experienced with javascript but this seems out of order, so I think the problem is that javascripts asynchronous nature causes the script to move forward without waiting for the ajax request to return results.

Does this make sense and how should I fix this?

Comment: You have to understand what means `asynchronous` to clearly understand this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible.

If you want to do something with the html `data` returned from the ajax, you should do it inside the success function, or call another function that does the job with the retured value.

Answer (score -1):

i think u should try `data.responseText();`

Comment: You should provide more detail on how to use `data.responseText()` in the code example of @user61629.